# Debug plugins page

Tags: error, plugin

I have a blank plugin page with no error. Error reporting is on and I have added this to the backend index:

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Nothing. Anyone know of another method? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have display_errors = On in php.ini?

Comment: Yes, they are on.

Comment: Are you logged in as super admin?

Comment: Yep, that also.

Comment: Can you try to disable zip compression in the config.php? $config['gzip_output'] = 'n';

Comment: Hmm, tried that. Nothing. Hmmmm.